# How to make a matrix organization chart?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-visio, visualization

I'm looking for a good way to do a matrix organization chart. My toolbox includes Powerpoint, Visio, Excel but none of these give matrix organization chart template out-of-the-box. What is the best way to do that kind of chart? Is there any other tool for creating these kind of charts?

Comment: I can't get in to it at the moment, but I think Visio is by far the best bet for this - You can also do it pretty well in powerpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article [Organizational Chart Template](http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/organizational-chart.html) suggests using Excel and offers 11 free templates of different types, including one Matrix Organizational Structure :

> **Why use Excel to create a Company Organization Chart?**
>
> - You can create a very large organizational chart and then use the
>     print settings to fit the entire org
>     chart onto a single page. Trying to
>     fit a large flow chart on a single
>     PowerPoint slide is harder because you
>     have to play with fonts and it's
>     harder to scroll around on the page
>     when you have it zoomed up.
> - It is very simple to align blocks of information either in columns or
>     rows. Think of the spreadsheet grid as
>     your "drawing grid". You can use
>     drawing guides and turn on a grid in
>     PowerPoint, but it's not as easy as
>     using the grid in Excel.
> - You can resize an entire row or column of blocks in your organization
>     chart by just resizing the row or
>     column. By default, Autoshapes in
>     Excel move and resize with the cells.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Our [org chart template collection](http://creately.com/diagram-community/examples/t/organization-chart) has quite few matrix organizational chart templates. You can directly edit them online by creating an account.

Disclosure: I work for Cinergix, makers of Creately.